# What are the parameters to the kernel function in an SVM?

Tags: svm, gaussian

I'm trying to understand kernel functions, particularly the gaussian/RBF function `K(a,b) = exp(-gamma||a-b||**2)`.

As I understand, this is computing a similarity measure for vectors a and b in part using euclidean distance. My question isn't about the specifics of this kernel, though.

What I don't understand: what are vectors `a` and `b` when you use this kernel in an SVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVM is a supervised learning algorithm, so there will be a training phase and a testing phase in which you use a sample of collected data.

A sample of data used for training is usually indicated with {x_i, y_i}, where x are real-valued attributes for each datum and y are the corresponding labels (See [wikipedia SVM page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine), at section "Linear SVM" for example). 
For each kernel K(a, b). the value "a" and "b" are the x_i and x_j of the data you have.

In the testing phase you will have only the set {x_i} and you want to estimate the corresponding y. Also in this case the "a" and "b" are the x_i and x_j of the data you have.

EDIT

K(a, b) is calculated for every pair (a, b) = (x_i, x_j), varying i and j. The kernel represents a dot product ([Kernel trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method)), defined on the feature space by the so called function phi. 
The SVM needs all the dot products of all the pairs because the hinge-loss comprehends a sum over i and j of all the dot products (that means of all the K(x_i, x_j)).

For example, if you have the set {x_i} = {x_1, x_2} you need 
K(x_1, x_1), K(x_1, x_2), K(x_2, x_1), K(x_2, x_2)

(For each kernel K(a,b) = K(b,a), being a dot product, then symmetric. In the end you don't need K(x_2, x_1))

Comment: What is x_j? From my view, you just renamed b to x_j. Does this mean it's computing for every combination of x pairs?